# R: Neural Networks to classify images as binary data (input and output)

Tags: r, image, neural-network, classification, binary-data

I'm diving in the world of the image classification in R, and I have a problem with the neural network I'm using to classify images. The main problem is that the predictions of my neural network are quite nonsense, but let's proceed with order. My data are all binary, all the dependent and independent variables.

My project is developing in this way:

> 1. import images, and translate them into numbers (using `{EBImage}`)
> 2. feed the neural network with those numbers (using `{neuralnet}`)
> 3. do some predictions about new pics (using `{neuralnet}`)

For the first point, I put all the path of the images in a .csv, I read them in R, I transformed them a bit, and created a nice dataframe.

```
# source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("EBImage")
library(EBImage)
library(neuralnet)

#  dataset
data <- read.csv("... path/images.csv", sep = ",")
u <- as.vector(as.factor(data[,1])) # input the path as vector
 To be clear, the dataset is something like:

images result type
path1  s      circle
path2  n      square
path3  n      bolt
path4  s      square
```

And the images are some very simple images done with paint, something like those: they are 21 in total, and most of them are only rotation of the following shapes. **My goal is to find the squares.**

[image][image][image][image]

Here a partial screenshot of the .csv. I've used more than the pics listed above:
[image]

So I input the images i this way, the point 1 of list.

```
# import the data and transformation
for(i in 1:length(u)){
         tau <- cbind(u,                           # bind by column
         data.frame(                               # put in a data frame
         t(                                        # trasp into column
         as.vector(                                # coerce as vector
         getFrame(                                 # take the first frame of the images (param. 1 last row)
         (imageData                                # extract data from image
         (resize                                   # resize (parameters w, h)
         (readImage(u[i]),w = 200, h= 50))),1))))) # read images
                      }
```

Now all the images have the same dimension, and each pixel is become a value 0 -1 in the dataframe's column.

```
# useful result of the dataframe
 data_0 <- data.frame(risultato = data$result,tau[,-1])
```

I've read that for neural network, the binary output should be used as contrasts.

```
# Binarize the categorical output
 data_0 <- cbind(data_0$risultato == 's',data_0)
 data_0 <- cbind(data_0$risultato == 'n',data_0)
 names(data_0)[1:2] <- c('n', 's')
 data_0 <- data_0[,-3]
 And here the training data (`data_1`) and the test data (`data_2`)    

 data_1 <- data_0[-12,]
 data_2 <- data_0[12,]
 str(data_1)
```

Now the point 2: train the neural network:

```
# first, let's dummyze the variables (to be sure)
set.seed(500)
n <- names(data_1) # columns' name
f <- as.formula(paste("~ ", paste(n, collapse = " + "))) # here the formula

# dummy
m <- model.matrix( 
                  f, 
                  data = data_1 
                  )[,-1]

# now let's write the formula for the neural network
mm <- colnames(m[,3:ncol(m)])
class(mm) # check the class
form.in<- as.formula(paste("sTRUE + nTRUE ~ ", paste(mm, collapse = "+"))) # here the neural network formula
```

And last the neural network:

```
mod2<-neuralnet(form.in,data=m,hidden=20)
```

After some time, let's do the point 3, the predictions:

```
compute(mod2,data_2[,-(1:2)])
```

And the result is

```
compute(mod2,data_2[,-(1:2)])$net.result
           [,1]         [,2]
12 0.5502895567 0.4499845316   But weirdly, the result is not correct, but the weird thing is that putting all the values of the training dataset:

> compute(mod2,data_1[,-(1:2)])$net.result
           [,1]         [,2]
1  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
2  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
3  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
4  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
5  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
6  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
7  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
8  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
9  0.5502895567 0.4499845316
10 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
11 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
13 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
14 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
15 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
16 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
17 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
18 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
19 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
20 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
21 0.5502895567 0.4499845316
```

The result are all the same!

I could not imagine which is the problem. I have not put too much pics, thinking that you can achieve the same result rotating the three samples above and put "s" on the circle, "n" on the others in the proper column. I do not know how to share all the pics, if you need them, please tell me how and I'll gladly give them to you. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might have swapped your "s" and "n" columns in `data_0`. By `cbind`ing them from the left you end up with having them ordered as `c('n', 's')`.